# ES6 import/export merge object with async await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, fs, es6-modules

I have two files called `config.js` and `config.json` and I want to merge them into one object and export it:

config.json

```
{
  "c": 3
}
```

config.js

```js
import fs from "fs";
import fse from "fs-extra";
import watch from "node-watch";

const config = {
  a: 1
  b: 2
}

//check does file exists
if (fs.existsSync('./src/config.json')) {
  //event emitter watch for changes in json
  const watcher = watch('./src/config.json', { recursive: true });
  //if json ready, then validate and merge
  watcher.on('ready', async function() {
    const importConfig = await fse.readJson('./src/config.json');
    //merge both default config from current file and json
    Object.assign(config, importConfig)
    //small validate function which checks that `json` can be merged
    const valid = await validationConfig(config)
    if (valid) {
      logger.info('Settings has been valid and imported successfully.');
    } else {
      process.exit(1);
    }
  });
}


//console.log(settings) a & b exists, but c does not
export { config };
```

But somehow, even with `fs.existsSync` export keyword doesn't wait for code inside `if` block to end, and ends before. How this problem can be solved?

Comment: You're only merging the JSON file contents when the watcher is ready (_in the future_); but you're displaying the contents of `config` _now_. If you want to merge _now_, then do so; JavaScript is not able to time-travel. :) You do not need node-watch to simply read the file. (You can still use node-watch to _update_ the configuration later.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

```
watcher.on('ready', async function() {
```

is a *callback*. The synchronous code below the callback - that is, the `export { config }` - will run before the callback finishes.

Export a Promise instead, one which resolves to the value of the loaded config:

```
const config = { a: 1, b: 2 };
export const configProm = !fs.existsSync('./src/config.json')
    ? Promise.resolve(config)
    : new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // <----------------------------
        const watcher = watch('./src/config.json', { recursive: true });
        watcher.on('ready', async function () {
            const importConfig = await fse.readJson('./src/config.json');
            Object.assign(config, importConfig)
            const valid = await validationConfig(config)
            if (valid) {
                logger.info('Settings has been valid and imported successfully.');
                resolve(config); // <----------------------------
            } else {
                process.exit(1);
                reject(); // ??
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: So, in this case, does `import { configProm } from "config.js";` in other file gives me access to the merged object directly? Or I should use `top-level-await` feature, to `await configProm` ?

Comment: You will be exporting a Promise, so in modules that use `configProm`, you'll have to wait for the Promise to resolve. You can use top-level await or any other method that waits for the Promise to resolve before getting to the underlying value.

Comment: @CertainPerfomance, could please provide me a bit more clarification before I mark this question as solved. Is there any way to avoid using `Promises` or `top-level-await` if I want to use `eventEmitters`? Does this problem relevant with event emitters and so on? I will be glad, even if you point me docs or article with a relevant theme.

Comment: A Promise is exported - there's no way to avoid the fundamental asynchronous nature. I guess you could use a callback too, but that's uglier. If multiple places in your code later requires this `config` and you don't want to make each of them have to handle the async-ness, consider using dependency injection instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65589980